Fine tuning LayoutLMv2 for Document question answering using custom data
I want to fine tune LayoutLMv2 for document question answering on custom data. Can somebody help me out on how to prepare the data for this task?
I need to prepare the data in the correct format, but due to very less resources on this, it is becoming very difficult. I request your help into this matter.
Thanks
